# How to solve the issue of getting garbage value on top of stack c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures

This is code to find out the position of the unbalanced bracket in the given input. If there is no unbalanced bracket then the output is Success. When I output the top of the stack I get garbage values in C++. How to avoid it? Why does it happen?
Here Bracket is the struct that contains the position of the element and the type of element.

```
int main() {
    std::string text;
    getline(std::cin, text);

    stack <Bracket> opening_brackets_stack;

    for (int position = 0; position < text.length(); ++position) {
        char next = text[position];
        if (next == '(' || next == '[' || next == '{') {
            Bracket *l1 = new Bracket(next, position + 1);
            opening_brackets_stack.push(*l1);
            cout<<opening_brackets_stack.top().type<<" " 
                <<opening_brackets_stack.top().position<<endl;          
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the declaration of Bracket

```
 struct Bracket 
 {
 char type;
 int position;

 Bracket(char type, int position) 
 {
    type =type;
    position=position;
 } 

bool Matchc(char c) {
    if (type == '[' && c == ']')
        return true;
    if (type == '{' && c == '}')
        return true;
    if (type == '(' && c == ')')
        return true;
    return false;
}


};
```

Comment: Please add the declaration of `Bracket`. Additionally, but probably unrelated to your problem, you probably do not need to call `new`. `Bracket l1(next, position + 1);` should be sufficient and removes a memory leak.

Comment: Yes I did try that, but did not help. I am still getting garbage value as the top of the stack.

Comment: Can you update the code so that it can be compiled and run so that we can test it ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? What output do you get and what values did you expect instead?

Comment: `a=a` rarely does anything useful.  Stop hiding the members of your struct with constructor parameters.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of problems with your code, but to get into specifically what your issues is.
It is assigning local variables to themselves instead of to the data members. 
Change

```
Bracket(char type, int position) 
 {
    type =type;
    position=position;
 }
```

to

```
Bracket(char type, int position) 
 {
    this->type =type;
    this->position=position;
 }
```

or use initializer lists and differing names

```
Bracket(char in_type, int in_position)
: type(in_type)
, position(in_position)
{
}
```

You also have memory leak here

```
Bracket *l1 = new Bracket(next, position + 1);
opening_brackets_stack.push(*l1);
```

this is better written with automatic storage duration as

```
Bracket l1{next, position + 1};
opening_brackets_stack.push(l1);
```

Comment: In the constructor you can also `Bracket(char type, int position) : type(type), position(position) {}`